# Does an inherited class automatically implement an Interface from its base class?

Tags: vb.net, inheritance, interface

Suppose I have piece of code like this:

```
Public Interface ISomething
    ....
End Interface

Public Class SomeClass
  Implements ISomething
    ....
End Class
```

Now, if I inherit from SomeClass like this:

```
Public Class InheritedClass
  Inherits SomeClass
    ....
End Class
```

will InheritedClass automatically implements ISomething, or must I use `Implements ISomething` in the InheritedClass' definition?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the interface will be inherited as well.

Comment: I knew I forgot something up there >.< ... anyways, thanks for the answer

Comment: Is it like that in C# and Java?

Answer (score 9):

The interface was already implemented by the base class.  Your derived class will thus implement it as well since it inherits the base class implementation.  If you want to *alter* the base class implementation then you should declare the implementation method(s) virtual so you can override them.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, Rewinder beats you by 6 minutes, so his/her answer is the one I accept. But I'll upvote yours :)

Comment: Hmm, somebody should mark Rewinder's post as helpful.  I'll take care of it then.

Comment: VB.Net doesn't auto implement base classes. C# does